# Automatic Login to myHub with Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge

I need automaticly login to myHub a360 with Autodesk Forge API (Data Management API).
I have user for read only and I need login user after base web page loaded.
Is here any way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. You need to show what you tried before you can get any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files on A360 or BIM360 belongs to the user, so he/she needs to authorize access. This is the [3-legged workflow](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-3-legged-token/) and must be done at least once. After you can store the refresh token and extend your permission.

Comment: It is a pity. In this case, I will have to do my own file manager. I know 3-leg autorization, it is works, but I need give to access for many people without a360 user.

Comment: Thakns for your answer @Augusto

Comment: Can I send username and password to a360 on backend side app?

Comment: You cannot, the user needs to authorize it manually, at least once.